# Travel between Thailand, Laos, Cambodia and Vietnam as US Citizen

Tags: us-citizens, thailand, vietnam, cambodia, laos

I know this is more of a general/generic question. However, I want to make sure this is feasible before doing it.

The plan is to fly into Chiang Mai, Thailand (from the US), and then fly to Luang Prabang, Laos. From there I will fly to Siem Reap, Cambodia, and then finally off to Hanoi, Vietnam. Finally back to the United States. Each of these tickets will be one way tickets.

I won't be in each country longer than the expected visa times. So there is no worries there.

I know I need a visa for both Cambodia and Vietnam (which I can apply online for both), and I will get a VOA for Thailand and Laos.

I know there are sometimes gotchas that you have to be aware of when doing cross country travel like this (Israel/Lebanon for example).

I'm sure the short answer is no, but, will there be any issues traveling from one country to the next?

Comment: I did this, but in a different order. It's fine. Are you flying to Hanoi? (I assume so since a bus route would really only make sense via HCMC....)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yes, I will be flying into Hanoi from Cambodia. I didn't think there would be an issue, but you never know.

Comment: Can you actually get the complete Vietnam visa online?  Or is it *only* the Invitation letter (then you do VoA with invitation letter at airport).  make sure you get that letter early.  The price of that letter increases **exponentially** within 48 hours of arrival date.

Comment: @JonGrah You get the invitation letter. I got mine only 24 hours after applying. It indicates to bring the letter along with passport photos (which you can also take at the airport). Be nice if this was like Australia where you get a full electronic visa

Answer (score 1):

You could have problems with VOA on Cambodian border. But making visa online prevent any issues. Also please check vacine\certificate obligations in every counrty on your way.
As far as I know there are no any other issues with your plans. Just a couple recommendations.
Traveling by bus everywhere will be cheaper rather than by air.  And travel on a cheap motorcycle everywhere will make your trip unforgettable. Be sure locals will clear the all details about that.
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was able to make the entire trip with zero issues - Thanks